# Android firebase implementation failed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

implementations for firebase is kept on failing the error is displayed in this image please check and help

link to image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhPR3.png
please open the link because to add an image we need to get some requirements 
in Stack Overflow
please help,

Comment: You're not allowed to directly post images because you're supposed to post text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

1. Build > Clean Project
2. Build > Rebuild Project

After this, click on "Try again".

Comment: how to clean project

Comment: adding few implementations solved my problem thanks for your time